# How i consume from a api restful with unity tiny?

Tags: typescript, unity-game-engine, facebook-instant-games

I'm doing a small project with UNITY Tiny for Facebook instant Games but I do not know how to consume an api rest because the philosophy of unity tiny is new and there is not much documentation? can you help me ?

Comment: This is just too broad for [SO]. You are better off just trying something and seeing how it works and coming back with a more focused, code based question. There are many tutorials and guides online for you to bootstrap yourself. Unfortunately, SO is a terrible tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

Since Unity Tiny projects run in the browser, you can use regular browser JavaScript (`XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`) to consume an API.

*Example*:

```
if (ut.Runtime.Input.getKeyDown(ut.Core2D.KeyCode.Space)) {
  fetch("http://www.google.com")
    .then(x => console.log(x))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```